# SimpleInjector - Decorators are not firing up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, cqrs, simple-injector

I'm using CQRS based on this [Link](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and using SimpleInjector to fire up my Decorators. But they aren't getting fired. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here's my **ICommandHandler** part:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : Command
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : Command<TResult>
{
}
```

And **BaseCommandHandler** part:

```
public abstract class BaseCommandHandler<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : Command
{
    public DbEntities Db { get; set; }

    public BaseCommandHandler(DbEntities db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    public BaseCommandHandler() : this(new DbEntities())
    {            
    }

    public abstract void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public abstract class BaseCommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> 
    : BaseCommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : Command<TResult>
{     
}
```

**SimpleInjector Configuration**:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(BaseCommandHandler<>).Assembly);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>));
```

Note: Both ICommandHandler and BaseCommandHandler reside in different library assemblies. This is done purposefully.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered two closed-generic decorators, instead of the open-generic types. This is your registration:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>));
```

What this configuration says is, for every `ICommandHandler<T>` implementation that is resolved, try to wrap it with an `LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>` when possible. Since you supplied the closed `LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>` however, it can only be applied to an  `ICommandHandler<Command>` implementation, but never to any subtype of command such as with `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>`.

The reason this is not possible, is because when someone requests an `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>`, it expects an implementation of this type, but `LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>` does not implement `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>`; it only implements `ICommandHandler<Command>`. So although a `LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<Command>` could wrap an `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>`, it can't be returned. It would cause an `InvalidCastException`.

So this should have been your registration:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(LoggerCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm! Thanks for the detailed answer.